# Surface Integral with Gauss Law

Tags: mathematical-physics, surfaces, gaussian-integral

Okay this is more a physical motivated problem, but since its basically mathematics I'll ask here :

> Given a vector field ***v(x)**=C* **x**/**|x|*** in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Calculate:
>
> a) the surface Integral $\int\limits_{\partial K_{0}}\! v \, \mathrm{d}f$ for the surface $\partial K_{0}$ of a sphere with radius *a* around zero using Gauß theorem.
>
> b) the integral $\int\limits_{\partial K_{b}}\! v \, \mathrm{d}f$ for the surface $\partial K_{b}$ of a spherealso with radius *a* which is moved the distance *b* away from zero along the $x$-Axis.(Again using Gauß theorem)

(Additionally: How to calculate the b) without Gauß to prove?)

Comment: Could you tell us where you are stuck or don't understand?

Comment: basically the b, what my integral should look like after it's been moved... (or what coordinates to use)

Comment: Also, what is $df$?

Comment: it's a surface you integrate over, so in this case the surface of a sphere... u can replace it with any kind of coordinates (in the a of course I used spherical coordinates dr, d(phi), d(theta) but in b im not sure

Comment: as i said the exercise is coming from physics, so I guess the notation is pretty messed up for u